# Does spark 2.3.1 has a way to specify watermark using Raw SQL?

Tags: apache-spark

Does spark 2.3.1 has a way to specify watermark using Raw SQL? I see the `Dataset.withWaterMark` however what I a looking for is a way I can specify watermark through Raw SQl. perhaps a UDF? can I write one?